# Gentzen and computer science

Tags: terminology, philosophy-of-science, mathematical-logic, computer-science

This is a cross-post from mathstack:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2584003/gentzen-and-computer-science?noredirect=1#comment5333947_2584003

I would like to learn a bit about the connections between Gentzen's discoveries in the 30's related to proof theory and, in particular, his sequent calculus, and the later development of computer languages. Could anyone elaborate a bit on that? I am particularly interested in knowning whether one can find in Gentzen some predecessor of a pointer to a memory address. If so, in which specific form?

Thanks in advance.